# Set global thousands separator for echarts

Tags: echarts

I am using apache echarts and I want to specify globally what the thousands separator should be. 
By default it is a comma: ie I put in a number of `5000` and what is shown is formatted as `5,000`.

I would like to specify different separator globally, or have it formatted automatically based on users locale is that possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it's impossible to set delimiter globally but Echarts already have API for format almost any value. If you need change value in tooltip use [`formatter`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#tooltip.formatter), it's component attribute with callback support. You can define callback and modify any tooltip data.