# Change decimal and thousands separator in axis and tooltip

Tags: r, echarts, echarts4r

I'm making plots using echarts4r. In my language, the separators for decimals and thousands are reversed from english, i.e. commas for decimals, dots for thousands.
How can I accomplish this for my charts? Here's an example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(echarts4r)
my_data <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=c(1000,2000,2500))

e_charts(my_data, x = x) %>% e_bar(y) %>% e_tooltip()
```

I'd like both the y axis and tooltip to have dots instead of commas in numbers.

I'd prefer doing it via Javascript in `formatter` arguments since I'm doing some other manipulations for detailed tooltips, but I'm not sure what to write for this purpose.

### Similar questions

[Remove comma in thousands in echarts4r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62932480/remove-comma-in-thousands-in-echarts4r)
But I'd rather change the symbols than remove it.
[Set global thousands separator for echarts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61934422/set-global-thousands-separator-for-echarts)
Wasn't answered with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is ony way how to tweak `formatter` to get the desired output:

```
library(dplyr)
library(echarts4r)
my_data <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = c(100.23, 2000.21, 2500.12))



e_charts(my_data, x = x) %>% 
  e_bar(y) %>% 
  e_tooltip(
    formatter = htmlwidgets::JS(
      "function(params) {
         var value = params.value[1].toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
         return value.toString().replace(/(\\d)(?=(\\d{3})+(?!\\d))/g, '$1.');
       }"
    )
  )
```

[image]